# The status bar can not back to the original place

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9zII.jpg)

As shown in figure, my screen had turned back to the vertical direction, but the status bar on the right, I use a cardboardSDK broadcast video

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this two methods to change status bar orientation to portrait.

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```